# What is the translation of "Actions speak louder than words" in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I would like to translate the sentence "Actions speak louder than words" into Latin.

"*Actiones seneca*" was the translation that Google translate provided. Is that accurate?

Comment: Different languages can be much more or less compact than others, but it would be a pretty impressive language indeed that had a specific word *Seneca* for 'speak louder than words'. (Short answer: no, *Seneca* is the name of a Roman philosopher and statesman, Google Translate has given a particularly terrible piece of nonsense in this case.)

Comment: Other websites that translate gave the exact same answer so thank you so much for saving me from a lifetime of embarrasment!! Very grateful here :)

Comment: It is an expression that my recently late father used to say to us all the time and it is what my siblings and I live by. It means words have no value without the actions to back them up. I wanted to translate it into Latin to make it more interesting for a memorial tattoo, so it does have to be literal. I want it to be my father's words. So I am very grateful to dbmag9 for saving me from making a terrible mistake. I will stick to the saying in English. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The expression

> Clarius facta quam verba loquuntur.

... is a literal translation of the English saying, but also a time-honoured Latin expression. I could not determine who coined it -- it does not seem to be ancient -- but judging by the Google Books hits, it has to be at least a few hundred years old. (Sometimes the words get shuffled around a bit, as it happens in Latin, but this seems to be a common version.)

Other Latin expressions with a similar meaning are the curt

> Facta, non verba!

(Actions, not (i.e., instead of) words!) and

> Acta virum probant.

(The actions prove the man), which seems to originate with a [painting](https://www.nationalgallery.org.uk/paintings/jan-steen-a-young-woman-playing-a-harpsichord-to-a-young-man) by the Dutch master [Jan Steen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jan_Steen) and possibly has a slightly risqué subtext. (Sine dubio et mulierem probant!)

Comment: "Clarius facta quam verba loquuntur" is the literal translation of "Actions speak louder than words"?

Comment: @Noa "More clearly" rather than "louder", but otherwise yes.

Comment: @cmw *clārius* refers to the force and loudness of one's voice and is thus a direct translation of 'louder'. 'more clearly, more distinctly, more comprehensibly' would call for various other translations such as *liquidius* (of sound), *articulātius* (of diction), *plānius* (of sense).

Comment: @Unbrutal_Russian The [dictionary](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dclarus) does not agree with your disagreement.

Comment: @cmw Please offer what you think is the Latin equivalent of 'to speak louder'.

Comment: @Unbrutal_Russian Please don't put words in my mouth. I think this word is fine for that, and I never said otherwise. That's why I upvoted this answer.

Comment: @cmw Please be assured that I never meant to put any words in your mouth. You've corrected "louder" to "more clearly", and I don't understand why. I think *clārius loquī* is a direct equivalent of 'to speak louder', and part of the reason is that I'm not aware of a better equivalent. The dictionary entry you linked also agrees with me, offering 'loud' as a translation, and [Smith & Hall translates](https://latinitium.com/latin-dictionaries/?t=sh15274) 'loud' as *clārus*. Would you be so kind and explain the reason for your correction if there's no better equivalent for 'louder' than *clārius?*

Comment: @Unbrutal_Russian I did not correct anything. I responded to Noa about what the words "literally" mean. I have no problem with Sebastian's answer.

Comment: I agree with @cmw: This answer is good and *clarius* is very suitable, and the most literal translation of it is perhaps indeed "more clearly" rather than "louder", but the difference is not of much relevance right here. If someone not familiar with Latin wants a literal translation, the word "clearer" is certainly worth a mention.